# Selenium in spring-boot application - Autowiring issue

Tags: java, selenium, spring-boot, javabeans, galen

I am trying to run a selenium test (done through [GalenFramework](http://galenframework.com)) in a spring-boot application. The issue I am facing is in the autowiring part. I am **not able to autowire the AppDetails class into my Test class because of 
 NULLPOINTER exception.**

I am getting the nullpointer exception while trying to run the test alone (either directly from `IntelliJ` or `mvn test -Dtest=TestClassName` method)
But I am able to run (`mvn spring-boot:run`) the application, which is not required even though I tried to run the application to make sure the value from yaml file (shirtuserurl) is reading correctly.

Why I used spring-boot for selenium ?
I want to load values from Application.yml file as the entire system here are set to use yaml file.

Here are the classes.

**Application.java class** 
[D:\workspace\galen-tester\galen-tester\src\main\java\com\shirt\library\galen\Application.java]

```
package com.shirt.library.galen;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.EnableDiscoveryClient;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public String getTestName() {
        return "some name";
    }
}
```

**Test Class** 
[D:\workspace\galen-tester\galen-tester\src\test\java\com\shirt\library\galen\user\UserTestUI.java]

```
package com.shirt.library.galen.user;

import com.shirt.library.galen.Application;
import com.shirt.library.galen.components.GalenTestConfig;
import com.shirt.library.galen.components.TestDevice;
import com.shirt.library.galen.models.AppDetails;
import com.galenframework.config.GalenConfig;
import com.galenframework.config.GalenProperty;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.io.IOException;

//@ActiveProfiles("test")
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
public class UserTestUI extends GalenTestConfig {

    @Autowired
    private AppDetails appDetails; <-- This comes as NULL 

    @Autowired
    String getTestName;

    @Test (dataProvider = "devices")
    public void test_user_onDevice(TestDevice devices) throws IOException {
        GalenConfig.getConfig().setProperty(GalenProperty.GALEN_RANGE_APPROXIMATION,"5");
        System.out.println("Full URL : " + appDetails.getFullURL());  <----- NULLPOINTER exception here 
        loadAppInBrowser("user");
        loginAuthWithCredentials();
        CheckLayout(devices);


    }
```

**AppDetails class** 
[D:\workspace\galen-tester\galen-commons\src\main\java\com\shirt\library\galen\models\AppDetails.java]

```
package com.shirt.library.galen.models;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class AppDetails {

    @Value("${shirtuserurl}")
    private String fullURL;


    //@Bean
    public String getFullURL() {
        return fullURL;
    }
}
```

I am trying to autowire a @Component under src\main\java\com\shirt... from src\test\java\com\shirt is that the problem ?

Let me know if anyone has any idea on it.

Note:
I am using spring-boot version 1.5.10.RELEASE

Comment: Show us the stacktrace of the error. Also, try to remove the `@ContextConfiguration` from the class test.

Answer (score 0):

try to use these annotations:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
```